# joda api to slice time range into interval

Tags: java, jodatime

I have to divide time range into interval of 15 minutes.
input time may be in format of 12 hrs or in 24 hrs format.
does joda provides any method to slice time range into required interval?

```
ex: 

    input:
    startTime: 08:00 AM or 08:00 endTime: 2:00 PM or 14:00

    output:
    08:00, 08:15, 08:30, 08:45...............
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: @Erwin Bolwidt: i'm new at joda. don't know how to do it using joda api. someone suggested me to use joda but i didn't find anything, is joda provide any method for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For increment in time just use time.plusMinutes() or time.plusHours().
 To check greter than or less han use time.isBefore() or time.isAfter().

```
for(LocalTime time = startTime; time.isBefore(endTime)  ; time = time.plusMinutes(15) ){
                         //operations
    }
```